# ".Result" doesn't not seem to be acting synchronously

Tags: post, asynchronous, c#-4.0, async-await

I have an API call that makes use of `.Result` to act synchronously.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/updatelastname", new StringContent(string.Format("UserId={0}&LastName={1}", userId, lastName),  Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).Result;
```

To see if the API has completed successfully I use the following `if..then` statement before proceeding.

```
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  // Something went wrong
}
```

What I am confused about is sometimes the api call completes without issue and then sometimes it does not. It seems like at times the code does not wait for the API call to complete and therefore the `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` is `false`.

Ideally I think it would be best to make the method `async` and use the `await` keyword on the API call, however the web app only targets .NET 4 at the moment and `async` and `await` are not supported until .NET v4.5.

Any thoughts on how I can ensure the API call completes before checking the `response.IsSuccessStatusCode`? Without moving to .NET v4.5+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the web app only targets .NET 4 at the moment and async and await are not supported until .NET v4.5.

It's the client (the one calling `PostAsync`), not the web app, that needs to support `await`. I'll assume that you mean that the client *is* a web app.

> sometimes the api call completes without issue and then sometimes it does not.

Sometimes it does not complete, you mean? As in, the code never returns from `Result`?

There are some scenarios where `Result` will deadlock, but I'd be surprised to find one on ASP.NET (to my knowledge, all `Result` deadlocks with `HttpClient` are only on some mobile platforms).

> It seems like at times the code does not wait for the API call to complete and therefore the response.IsSuccessStatusCode is false.

What you're suspecting isn't possible. `Result` will block until the HTTP request completes. If `IsSuccessStatusCode` returns `false`, then that's because the API returned a non-success status code.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! You are correct the client callingthe API is indeed a web app. Whatt I meant by "does not complete" is that the `IsSuccessStatusCode` sometimes returns false yet when I look at the api call nothing is wrong.

Comment: @webworm: If `IsSuccessStatusCode` returns `false`, then the WebAPI did in fact return an error code. The [implementation of that property](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs#L123) is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Something else must be going on. I need to find out what status code is being returned. Thanks for the help! Love your `async` book by the way.